# How to keep a value from resetting in a loop?

Tags: loops, python-3.7, integer-arithmetic

I have been trying to set up a health system for my school project but the value keeps resetting regardless of the fact that monster_health is outside of the loop, my friends and I can't seem to fix this.

Code:

```
monster_health = 100
while monster_health > 0:
    playeraction = input('Placeholder beast wants to fight you!!\n1) Basic Attack')
    print(monster_health)
    if playeraction == 1:
        monster_health = monster_health-7
        continue
    if monster_health <= 0:
        print('You killed the monster!! Gain nothing, this is a test you barbarian')
        break
```

Output:

```
Placeholder beast wants to fight you!!
1) Basic Attack
100 #should print 97 but fails to
```

Comment: Please edit the question to include the actual output and the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace

```
    if playeraction == 1:
```

with

```
    if playeraction == "1":
```

or:

```
    if int(playeraction) == 1:
```

Because your input is string format and not an integer and 1 != "1".

Answer (score 0):

From your code, you are printing the monster health before updating it, so it will be "100" (the initial value) the first time.

```
while monster_health > 0:
  playeraction = input('Placeholder beast wants to fight you!!\n1) Basic Attack')
  print(monster_health) # at this time, it is still 100
```